# Can NS records contain IPV6 addresses?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have some local domains, and I want them to be accessible over ipv6 only. I'm using unbound.

```
local-zone: "example.com" redirect
local-data: "example.com. 2562000 IN NS 2607:XXXX:XXXX:XXX::XXX"
local-zone: "test.example.com" redirect
local-data: "test.example.com. 2562000 IN NS 2607:XXXX:XXXX:XXX::XXX"
local-data: "test.example.com. 2562000 IN AAAA 2607:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX::XXX"
```

But I can't find for sure, if you are allowed to have IPV6 addresses as NS records, as pretty much every one I find in the internet uses domains...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NS` records can only ever have names as their value. No IPv4 addresses, no IPv6 addresses.

Ie, you need a name with address records (`A` and/or `AAAA`) that you can refer to in the `NS` record.

Comment: Weird. Are you sure? Then why my apps aren't having any issues with the `ǸS` records being ipvx addresses ?

Comment: @Freedo ipvx? If you mean ipv4, I think you are getting things confused. If you were to write an ipv4 address as the value that would be parsed as an all-numeric *name* (as the value can only ever be a name and the format is compatible). That would however be a name that doesn't exist (`NXDOMAIN`). Other than human input, DNS is not text-based, things have clearly defined types.

Comment: I see. Is it ok to make the ns record be my own domain ? like domain `example.com` and ns record is `example.com.`

Comment: @Freedo Technically yes, however I would suggest eg `ns.example.com` in that case, so that you can use `example.com` for whatever you like. (Also, expect that people may have overlooked the option of using `example.com` there as practically no one does that, potentially throwing a fit over it when you try to delegate there or if you run some validity check.)

Comment: OK thanks. I'll only use this domain in unbound with my devices connected directly to it, so I don't publicly control the domains. thanks for the info!